# Transforming a uniform random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider a random variable $X\sim U[\underline{x},\overline{x}]$, for $\underline{x}>1$. I want to characterize (obtain PDF/CDF) a transformation:

$$Y=aX-\log X$$

where $a>0$, and $\underline{x}$ is "high enough" for $Y$ to be always positive.

Normally, the way to proceed when studying transformations of the form $Y=f(X)$ is to invert $f$ and study $f^{-1}(Y)$ in order to characterize the associated PDF of $Y$. However, this is clearly not possible for the function above, since it cannot be inverted algebraically.

Can you suggest other approaches for characterizing $Y$?

Comment: Can you say something about $\underline{x},\overline{x}$?

Comment: I do not need to impose much on them, other than, perhaps $\underline{x}$ being "high enough" in for $Y$ to be always positive ($a>0$).

Comment: This is what I think too. Maybe you can use [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Trying a few values of $a$ and plotting histograms of large random samples should be enlightening.  You'll see that there is a big drop in probability density at $a$.

Comment: Z is maybe a better name: As an approximation you can use the series expansion of $\ln(Z+1)$ up to the second order, where $Z+1=X$

Answer (score 0):

This is an extended comment (until someone can supply the necessary algebraic justification as many times knowing what the answer probability is gives one an idea as to how to proceed to justify it).

Using *Mathematica* a function that will supply the probability density function for

$$Z=a U - \log(U)$$

where $U\sim \text{Uniform}[u_{\text{lower}},u_{\text{upper}}]$ at a value $z$ is

```
pdf[z_, a_?NumericQ, lower_?NumericQ, upper_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{zmin, zLeft, zRight, zz, density, dLeft, pdfLeft, dRight, pdfRight, w, dist},
  If[lower < 1/a < upper, 
   dLeft = TransformedDistribution[a u - Log[u], u \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{lower, 1/a}]];
   pdfLeft = (PDF[dLeft, zz][[1, 1, 1]]) /. zz -> z;
   dRight = TransformedDistribution[a u - Log[u], u \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1/a, upper}]];
   pdfRight = (PDF[dRight, zz][[1, 1, 1]]) /. zz -> z;
   zmin = 1 + Log[a];
   zLeft = a lower - Log[lower];
   zRight = a upper - Log[upper];
   w = (1/a - lower)/(upper - lower);
   If[zLeft < zRight,
    density = Piecewise[{{w pdfLeft + (1 - w) pdfRight, zmin <= z <= Min[zLeft, zRight]},
       {(1 - w) pdfRight, Min[zLeft, zRight] < z <= zRight}}, 0],
    density = Piecewise[{{w pdfLeft + (1 - w) pdfRight, zmin <= z <= Min[zLeft, zRight]},
       {w pdfLeft, Min[zLeft, zRight] < z <= zLeft}}, 0]
    ],

   dist = TransformedDistribution[a u - Log[u], u \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{lower, upper}]];
   density = PDF[dist, z]]]
```

For example, suppose $a=2$ and $u_{\text{lower}}=0$ and $u_{\text{upper}}=1$.  The pdf is

```
pdf[z, 2, 0, 1]
```

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{W_{-1}\left(-2 e^{-z}\right)}{2 \left(W_{-1}\left(-2 e^{-z}\right)+1\right)}-\frac{W_0\left(-2 e^{-z}\right)}{2 \left(W_0\left(-2 e^{-z}\right)+1\right)} & 1+\log (2)\leq z\leq 2 \\
 -\frac{W_0\left(-2 e^{-z}\right)}{2 \left(W_0\left(-2 e^{-z}\right)+1\right)} & 2<z\leq \infty  \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$$

where $W_k$ is the Lambert $W$ function.

As a feeble test consider taking a large random sample from this distribution and overlay the proposed density function over the histogram:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
uu = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 100000];
zz = 2 uu - Log[uu];
Show[Histogram[zz, 1000, "PDF"],
 Plot[Evaluate[pdf[z, 2, 0, 1]], {z, 1.5, 2.7}, Frame -> True,
  PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 12}},
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1/2]]
```

[image: Histogram and pdf]

I'll include the general formula in the very near future.